# How to side by side align two input bars in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to side by side align two input bars in html and css. This is to make up a form. I would like something like this.[side by side bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1DZT.png)

Answer (score 0):

So given that you dont have anything yet I'm just gonna put out an answer:

```css
label { width: 200px; float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; }
span { display: block; margin: 0 0 3px; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; }
input { width: 200px; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="email">
    <span>Email</span>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </label>
  <label for="password">
    <span>password</span>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  </label>
</form>
```

Hopes this helps